# wp7 silverlight canvas displays black screen after tombstoning

Tags: windows-phone-7, canvas, tombstoning

I have a screen in my wp7 app with only a canvas, used to display a graph.

I handle the page loaded event to draw the graph, by adding lines to the graph children, the lines are stored in a list variable in App.xaml.cs.

edit: here is my draw line function

```
    private void drawLine(Line line, Point start, Point end, Color color)
    {            
        line.X1 = start.X;
        line.Y1 = start.Y;

        line.X2 = end.X;
        line.Y2 = end.Y;            

        line.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(color);

        graph.Children.Add(line);
    }
```

I handle the tombstoning by storing/loading the lines in the settings.

I placed a breakpoint in the page loaded method, the lines are restored correctly after tombstoning, and the lines are added to the graph canvas children, yet the canvas displays a black screen.

How do i solve this ?

Comment: Not knowing how you're drawing your graph it wil be hard to say. Can you show some code to demonstrate what you're doing.

Comment: Ok, i added the draw line function i made, i loop on the data and call this function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not clear from your code how you're storing or recreating the data/lines the data you store during tombstoning shoudl be a collection of objects containing the start point, end point and color.

You should be creating new lines each time you are adding a line to your graph/canvas.